# Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 losing focus on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dragon-naturally-speaking

Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.50.000.065 Professional very often loses focus when I dictate on Windows 10 Enterprise. E.g., if I say "Dragon NaturallySpeaking", then it might happen that only "Dragon Natur" is transcribed, and the field where the text is input loses its focus. I have seen the issue appears in Google Chrome, Eclipse, and HipChat.

What could be the issue? It works fine with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that Dragon 12.5 is not officially compatible with Windows 10 and the corresponding Chrome plugin neither. I've had massive unexplainable issues with Dragon 12.5 on Windows 10. If it works, consider yourself lucky.

If a reinstall does not resolve your issues, you should use the dictation box in Chrome.

Comment: The dictation box is slow and Dragon 13+ is incompatible with most programs. (one has to go through the dictation box )